# Can we delete a PowerBI Dashboard using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerbi

I am trying to copy Power BI Dashboard from one workspace to the other using below code

```
New-PowerBIDashboard -Name $dashboard_name -WorkspaceId $target_workspace_ID
```

The Dashboard is created successfully but in case a dashboard with same name exist the it is not being overridden instead I see 2 dashboards with same name. Is there a way I can delete the existing dashboard from target using powershell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the powershell command for deleting PowerBIDashboard doesnot exist.  And there is not a rest api existing which allows deleting a dashboard programmatically currently. You might have to delete it from the UI.

[Here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/32536147-delete-a-dashboard-via-the-api) is a user voice to support Deleting a dashboard via the API. You can vote it up. Or you can create a new one for your own.